# When I click the back button, it takes me to the same page I'm currently on

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, browser, browser-history

I'm looking at a web site developed by someone else and am trying to troubleshoot an issue where the back button doesn't function correctly. Because this is not my code, I'm not exactly sure where the best places to prioritize my troubleshooting would be.

I'm trying to figure this out quickly - my questions are: What are some common things that would cause this? What are some areas to check that are very likely to be the culprit?

Here is the bug in action. If you click on any of the example portfolio items and then try to use the browser's own back button, you're taken back to the same page. I believe this is an issue of the routing in Angular but I don't know that for sure. Any ideas?

Comment: You have more than one problem. For example using the back button does bring me back to the previous page the first time, but the navigation item is still highlighted for the other page. At this point if I use the back button again then it simply stays on the same page like you described.

Comment: Looks like something is redirecting, or setting the new page twice. If you click and hold your back button you can see the entire history.

Comment: Great looking website, but it takes hours to load..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the back button issue, you should make all your hrefs point to #/route_name instead of #route_name in your html
for example change :

```
<a href="#about"  ....   </a>
```

To:

```
<a href="#/about"   ....      </a>
```

I tested the solution on your site and the back button worked like a charm.

Comment: As soon as I added this and made your suggested change, things worked:

    ```$('[ng-app]').on('click', 'a', function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    });```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about angular but the behavior could be because of the following code in compiled.min.js file. **The last 4-5 lines in this code snippet are important** and which might be causing this issue. Have a look at it and probably you can figure it out:

```
angular.module("Site", ['ngSanitize']).config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = !0, delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"], $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(function ($q, $location, $rootScope) {
        return function (promise) {
            //start spinner
            /*  $rootScope.element = $('.container')
            $rootScope.element.css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $rootScope.spinner = $rootScope.spinner ? $rootScope.spinner : startSpinner(); */
            return promise.then(
            // Success: just return the response
            function (response) {
                return response;
            },
            // Error: check the error status to get only the 401
            function (response) {
                if (response.status === 404) $location.url('/404');
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        }
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "views/homepage.html",
        controller: "homeC"
    }).when("/about", {
        templateUrl: "views/about.html",
        controller: "RouteC"
    }).when("/about/our-team", {
        templateUrl: "views/our-team.html",
        controller: "aboutC"
    }).when("/who-we-are", {
        templateUrl: "views/page.html",
        controller: "RouteC"
    }).when("/what-we-do", {
        templateUrl: "views/page.html",
        controller: "RouteC"
    }).when("/about/manifesto", {
        templateUrl: "views/manifesto.html",
        controller: "RouteC"
    }).when("/about/testimonials", {
        templateUrl: "views/testimonials.html",
        controller: "testimonialC"
    }).when("/about/awards", {
        templateUrl: "views/awards.html",
        controller: "RouteC"
    }).when("/services", {
        redirectTo: "/services/design"
    }).when("/services/marketing", {
        templateUrl: "views/services-marketing.html",
        controller: "services_marketing"
    }).when("/services/design", {
        templateUrl: "views/services-design.html",
        controller: "services_design"
    }).when("/services/ecommerce", {
        templateUrl: "views/services-ecommerce.html",
        controller: "services_ecommerce"
    }).when("/services/development", {
        templateUrl: "views/services-development.html",
        controller: "services_development"
    }).when("/services/mobile", {
        templateUrl: "views/services-mobile.html",
        controller: "services_mobile"
    }).when("/services/marketing/:slug", {
        templateUrl: "views/services.html",
        controller: "services_marketing_internal"
    }).when("/services/:slug", {
        templateUrl: "views/services.html",
        controller: "services_internal"
    }).when("/portfolio", {
        redirectTo: "/portfolio/website"
    }).when("/portfolio/:slug", {
        templateUrl: "views/portfolio.php",
        controller: "portfolioC"
    }).when("/portfolio/:category/:slug", {
        templateUrl: "views/portfolio-single.php",
        controller: "portfolio_internal"
    }).when("/blog-home", {
        templateUrl: "views/blog-home.html",
        controller: "RouteC"
    }).when("/blog-post", {
        templateUrl: "views/blog-post.html",
        controller: "RouteC"
    }).when("/contact", {
        templateUrl: "views/contact.php",
        controller: "contactC"
    }).when("/debug", {
        templateUrl: "views/qunit.html",
        controller: "qunitC"
    }).when("/404", {
        templateUrl: "views/error-404.html"
    }).when("/sitemap", {
        templateUrl: "views/sitemap.php"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/404"
    });

    //$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!'); //This seems to be the code which handles the redirect.
}).run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$apply.pathTo = function (url) {
        $location.path(url);
    };
```

Comment: This was one of the first things that stuck out to me but removing that entirely didn't change anything. I have a working solution, however, as marked as 'answer'.